# Looking for a translation of "end credits"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, new-latin, neologism

End credits are a namelist shown at the end of a video work.

I am looking for an expression for it that is short enough for lyrics.

I wonder if ***index finalis*** ("final list") is accurate and understandable enough.

> **Edit:** I found the Greek word ***catalogus*** can also mean a namelist.

Comment: finalis is closer to bounded than to final, I suggest index auctorum

Comment: @John I need to emphasize the "final" meaning here, how about ***postremus*** or ***extremus***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to emphasise the fact that these credits are at the end, as you mentioned in your comment, here are a few options:

- *index postrema* should be used if there are several credits and you are talking about the last one,
- *index extrema*/*index finalis*/*index terminalis* are quite close and should be used if the index marks the end of the show, if it is its extreme part, its limit.

I have a slight preference for *index terminalis*.